# Name (reference?) for lax monoidal functors that are 'full, or surjective, on monoids'?

Tags: category-theory, terminology, monoidal-categories

A lax monoidal functor $F$ takes monoids to monoids. Is there a name for a lax monoidal functor that is 'full' or surjective with respect to this property? In other words, the functor $F : \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ gives rise to $\hat{F} : \textbf{Mon}(\mathcal{C}) \rightarrow \textbf{Mon}(\mathcal{D})$. Is there a name for when $\hat{F}$ is surjective on those monoids defined on the image of $F$?

Formally, if the lax structure is given by $i : 1 \rightarrow F(1)$ and $m : F(A) \otimes F(B) \rightarrow F(A \otimes B)$, and I have a monoid given by $1 \rightarrow F(A)$ and $F(A) \otimes F(A) \rightarrow F(A)$, then I get a monoid $ F(1) \rightarrow F(A)$ and $ F(A \otimes A) \rightarrow F(A)$ where this diagram commutes:

[diagram http://quicklatex.com/cache3/ql_04dbb0d2e991a5f32dbb93b3cb78afcb_l3.png](http://quicklatex.com/cache3/ql_04dbb0d2e991a5f32dbb93b3cb78afcb_l3.png)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "full with respect to this property"?

Comment: Sorry if my wording is confusing! I mean that, since $F$ sends monoids to monoids by precomposing with the lax structure, is there a name for when any monoid defined on the image of $F$ `comes from' one in the domain in the way specified above. I'll edit the question.

Comment: I'd suggest something like: '*monoidally surjective* functor'